# Getting different result when debugging and running (C#)

Tags: winforms

So, I taking a random number by using Random object, to choose how many UserControls (actually, to randomly choose) I want for this task, and inside each UserControl I user Random object again, to get a random number to put in my UC. But for some reason, when I run(Ctrl+F5) the program, each UserControl contains the same number, for example , 5 UC's with the number 1 in them.
I saw in an other thread that you should declare on the variable (Random r for example) before the loop (the loop that I make the user controls) but I can't because I use Random in the UserControl's Constructor .

The loop that I make X user controls is:(num is the number we got from the Random.Next())
    for(int i=0;i

Comment: Create only **one** instance of the Random class.  Creating more than one at the same time just gets you the same random numbers from each since they all have the same seed.  Make it public and static so you can get to it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick example of static `Random` member in a UserControl:

```
public partial class ucSomething : UserControl
{

    private static Random R = new Random(); // only ONE instance of Random that gets reused across all ucSomething's...

    public ucSomething()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int number = R.Next(1, 11); // 1 to 10 inclusive
        for(int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
        {
            // ... something ...
        }
    }

}
```